# Как в мобильной версии сделать верхний отступ при прокрутке к секции календаря?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

У меня на сайте установлен вот такой календарь, как на [демо](https://pinpoint.world/demos/wordpress-booking/product/booking-days/)

Есть одна проблемка в моб разрешениях: когда посетитель выбирает дату - его прокручивает до поля выбора опций **extras**, но, в силу того, что у меня в отличие от демо, есть меню, которое в моб версиях фиксировано сверху на `80px`, то это меню перекрывает поле выбора и человек его не видит и не сразу понимает, что нужно открутить назад.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке к этому полю был сверху отступ на высоту меню?

Comment: Использовать `@media`, не пробовал?

Comment: @MegaRoks как именно? подробнее можете пояснить?

Comment: Как обрабатываете клик по календарю?

Comment: @Mully в каком смысле обрабатываете клик? У вас перед глазами демо (в описании) - библиотека календаря одна, работает все точно так же, только у меня фиксированное меню сверху, которое перекрывает поле

Comment: @Вася, вы даже не указали в каком направлении думать и двигаться, не выложили своих попыток и реализаций. Приложите примеры своего кода, как вы пытались решить данную проблему сами, напомню что здесь не фриланс, а с вашим "как на демо", я могу ответить "вам сюда http://google.com"

Comment: @Mully спасибо за совет - уже сам вышел на ответ ниже. Если у вас получится это сделать изящнее без правки файлов плагина - я зачту ваш ответ как более правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же можно сделать без правки файлов плагина, для этого нужно указать смещение указанное в файле плагина и новое значение:

```js
(function($) {
  var scrollToYOriginFn = DOPPrototypes.scrollToY;
  DOPPrototypes.scrollToY = function(position, speed) {
    var shift = -180,
        shiftOrigin = 50;
    if (res = document.querySelector('[id^="DOPBSPCalendar-reservation"]')) {
      pos = $('#' + res.id).offset().top + $('#' + res.id).height() - $(window).height() + shiftOrigin;
      if (position === pos) position += shift - shiftOrigin;
    }
    scrollToYOriginFn.apply(scrollToYOriginFn, arguments);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

При этом функция scrollToYOrigin сохраняется в дубликате scrollToYOriginFn и вызывается как обычно через scrollToYOrigin.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто.
Укажите для фиксированного меню `z-index` выше, чем у блока с контентом, в котором календарь лежит. Примерно так:

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #555656;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.menu span:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.section {
  padding: 10px;
}

.one {
  background-color: #ccf;
}

.two {
  background-color: #fcc;
  min-height: 1000px;
}

.calendar {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #ffc;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <span>Menu item 1</span>
  <span>Menu item 2</span>
  <span>Menu item 3</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="section one">
    Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="calendar">Calendar here</div>
    <br/>
    <br/> Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
  </div>
  <div class="section two">
    Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here.
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: вы совершенно не разобрались в вопросе, перечитайте внимательно: у меня поле выпадает за экран, а не календарь меню перекрывает

Comment: Я бы разобрался в вопросе, если бы вы потрудились более внятно его сформулировать изначально. А так - миль пардон.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было в следующем - в плагине в файле **jquery.dop.frontend.BSPCalendar.js** изменил в строке значение с *+50* до *-180* и скролл стал останавливаться в нужном месте

```js
if ($('#DOPBSPCalendar-reservation' + ID).offset().top + $('#DOPBSPCalendar-reservation' + ID).height() > $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
  DOPPrototypes.scrollToY($('#DOPBSPCalendar-reservation' + ID).offset().top + $('#DOPBSPCalendar-reservation' + ID).height() - $(window).height() - 180);
}
```